# A counterpart for BufUnload,BufDelete event but gets fired after a buffer is unloaded

Tags: buffers, autocmd

I've defined an autocommand that essentially checks for the remaining buffers' `filetype`, and for now by relying on `BufUnload` or `BufDelete`, the unloaded buffer still gets detected as being present at the buffer list when looping through the buffers. Is there a workaround or possibly an event that gets fired after unloading or deleting a file buffer ?

Comment: The states "loaded" and "listed" are completely independent one from another. You question is unclear.

Comment: @Matt Either one of them. I was generally looking for a way to capture the event after an unload or delete of a buffer.

Comment: Do you know what is the difference between `bufexists()`, `bufloaded()` and `buflisted()`? What does `:bdelete` do and how it differs from `:bwipeout`?

Comment: I'm already aware of the difference between them.what i'm trying to say is that prior to deleting or outright wiping, the available events get fired before even anything take effect.

Comment: Have you read the corresponding help topics? They all say exactly the word **before**. And there is no "after" event, because it is not needed. Say, BufUnload triggers, and immediately after it Vim frees buffer lines content. Both pre- and post- events exist only for non-trivial actions.

Comment: _ Say, BufUnload triggers, and immediately after it Vim frees buffer lines content._ and that's the drawback in my autocommand. the autocommand essentially call a function that check buffers, and when vim fires the event before unloading/wiping the buffer, it would still be visible -event though it's in its way to be deleted- for the function. If there's a workaround for this limitation, i'm also open to it.

Comment: One extra "if" to skip that buffer. Don't see any problem.